# Change value of each td > input with JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple function to re-create id's in a table but it's not giving me the expected output. I am by no means an expert in jquery so it's probably something simple.

```
$("#myTable tr").each(function (index) {
    if (index > 0) {
        $(this).find(".tdWithId > input").val(index);
        console.log($(this).find(".tdWithId > input").val());
    }
});
```

In the console output, the values look correct (1, 2, 3, etc.), but when I inspect the html I still see the previous values (value="1", value="2", value="4", etc.).

What am I missing?

**Update:**

When I do this from console after the fact you can see what I mean.

```
$(".tdWithId>input").val();
output: "1"

$(".tdWithId>input")
output: [<input name="[0].Details[0].ID" type="text" value="2">]
```

Comment: What does your table html look like? Do you only had one `td` with an `input` per row?

Comment: @mafafu Well it's looking for td with a certain class > input but there's only one td with that class per row

Comment: Oh, I thought maybe there were more than one and they would all get the same value and was going to suggest moving the `td > input` selector into the main selector for your `each`. Still wouldn't hurt to have the html or a fiddle or something.

Comment: This looks like the case brought up in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20446948/1883647). There is a difference between an element's *properties* and its *attributes*.

Comment: @ajp15243 I think you're probably right, thanks. That makes alot of sense. Learn something every day :)

Comment: You wrote `re-create id's` do you mean the value of each input `<input value=1>` or do you mean the id of the element `<input id=1 value=foo>` ? 
Did Davids reply answer your question?

Comment: @threeFourOneSixOneThree It's a column of ids for the data in the table not the id attribute, sorry for the confusion. And yes I can confirm that David and ajp15243 were correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change this

```
$(this).find(".tdWithId > input").val(index);
```

to this:

```
$(this).find(".tdWithId > input").attr('value', index);
```

Comment: It's possible this won't update the property on the input that's used during form submission. I would have to test, but it's something to verify before going with this approach.

Comment: @ajp15243 Good point. I will certainly test that, although I think it will work.

Comment: @aw04 You could also just try setting both `.val()` and `.attr()`. It's also possible that setting `.attr()` will internally set the property as well, in which case this answer will work as is (but I'm fairly certain it doesn't work like that).

Comment: @ajp15243 I need to do some further coding before I can test that, but I will update when I find out