# jquery .html() not getting latest selected value

Tags: javascript, jquery

jquery .html() not getting latest selected value, code here

```
<div id="testDiv">
<select id="mySel">
    <option  value="1">opt 1</option>
    <option selected value="2">opt 2</option>
    <option value="3">opt 3</option>
    <option value="4">opt 4</option>
</select>
</div>
```

and script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mySel').val('3');
var divContent = $('#testDiv').html();
alert(divContent);
});
```

getting an output like this

```
 <select id="mySel">
        <option  value="1">opt 1</option>
        <option selected value="2">opt 2</option>
        <option value="3">opt 3</option>
        <option value="4">opt 4</option>
    </select>
```

'selected' not getting changed, i need output like this

```
 <select id="mySel">
        <option  value="1">opt 1</option>
        <option  value="2">opt 2</option>
        <option selected value="3">opt 3</option>
        <option value="4">opt 4</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: You're seeing this behavior because [element properties and attributes are different](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20446948/1883647). If you want the markup attributes to change with the underlying element properties, you'll need to manually change the `selected` attribute on the `<option>`s.

Comment: input text having similar problem,  $('#txtId').val('new value'); it not working . finally  $('#txtId').attr('value', 'new value');   worked fine. no other option for select?

Comment: This is because `.val()` changes the underlying property on the input element, which is *not* reflected in markup attributes, but *is* used in things like form posts. Using `.val()` after setting it will get the updated value, even if markup doesn't show that. You only need to change the attribute if you care about the actual markup attribute, as opposed to the underlying property.

Comment: any other option (as like .attr() )   for select ?

Comment: You can use `.attr()`, it will just have to be on the `<option>`s instead of the `<select>`, per the below answers.

Comment: Why do you need that in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#mySel').val('4');
$("#mySel").find('option').removeAttr("selected");
$("#mySel option[value='4']").attr("selected","selected");
var divContent = $('#testDiv').html();
alert(divContent);
});
```

Output:

```
<select id="mySel">
    <option value="1">opt 1</option>
    <option value="2">opt 2</option>
    <option value="3">opt 3</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="4">opt 4</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

For your desired output you will need to add a script to move the `selected` attribute to the correct `<option>` when the user changes the value.  By default the select list will not modify your markup based on the user's actions.

Comment: input text having similar problem,  $('#txtId').val('new value'); it not working . finally  $('#txtId').attr('value', 'new value');   worked fine